# How to mask images in Keynote into circles?

Tags: graphics, keynote

I have a bunch of photos that I need on a single slide, and I'd like them all to be shown as circles.

Can I do that out-of-the-box with Keynote?

Answer (score 66):

**Yes.**

This works for any shape. Here's how:

1. Draw a shape.
2. Resize it to the desired size.
3. Position the shape over the image.
4. Select both by shift-clicking them.
5. Choose **Format** → **Image** → **Mask with Shape** from the menu (these menu items are from Keynote 6.5.2, might be different for your version)
6. Mask the image as you'd usually do (by dragging, resizing).
7. Click **Done**.

Comment: In older versions, e.g. Keynote 09 v 5.3 (1170), it's... **Format** > **Mask with Shape** > **Oval**, which starts as a circle and can be sized to include both circles and ovals.

Answer (score 32):

Actually, it is unnecessary to create a shape in order to mask the image.

- Place an image on the slide
- Select the image
- In the Menu Bar, go to **Format > Image > Mask with shape > [select shape]**

Now drag the mask as desired.

Set this image as a **Media Placeholder** by selecting the image then, **Format > Advanced > Define as Media Placeholder**

Copy the image as many times as desired on the slide and then drag new images to them. The mask will be applied to the new image as well.

[image: Masking Image menu]

[image: Apply Mask]

[image: Masked image result]

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply! I am struggling to get this working for Keynote 10.1. Any ideas?

Comment: All you have to do, usually, is make sure the image you want masked has been selected then follow the menu instructions above. What issue in particular are you facing? Cheers

Comment: In Keynote 11 this is on the Format/Arrange alternatives side panel. Union, Subtract, ... as icons at the bottom of that dialogue.